# Getting value from a span tag on a web page which built by reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

I am very new to web design and development so some things might be wrong in my request. Basically, I have a web page with a bunch of span tags like this 
ex:

[image: example of span tag]

Those span tags are the part of relatively big DOM tree and have a lot of ancestors.

As I understand, web page built by reactjs. Now my question is how in an efficient way, using JavaScript only I can get those values?

If you need additional info, please, do not hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select all `<span>` elements which have the attribute `data-reactid`. Then you can get the reactid using `.getAttribute("data-reactid")` and the value by grabbing the spans childNode:

**Example code**

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("span[data-reactid]");
elements.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry.getAttribute("data-reactid")+ ": " + entry.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
});
```

**PhantomJS Example**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

var url = "http://learngitbranching.js.org/?demo";
var fileName = "output";

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.loadImages = false; 

page.open(url, function(status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if(status === "success") {

        var values = page.evaluate(function () {
                var array = [].map.call( document.querySelectorAll('span[data-reactid]:not(:empty)'), function(value, index) {return value;});
                return [].map.call(array.filter(function (value) {return (value.childNodes != undefined && value.childNodes[0].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE);}), 
                    function (data) { return {reactid : data.getAttribute("data-reactid"), value : data.childNodes[0].nodeValue}; }); 
            });

        var string = "";

        values.forEach(function(entry) {
            string = string + entry.reactid+ ": " + entry.value + "\n";
        });

        var path = fileName+'.txt';
        fs.write(path, string, 'w');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Frederick! Might be you can also give me a hint how would I adopt it for phantomjs evaluate() function. I have this so far

var content = page.evaluate(function () {
            return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-reactid=".0.2.1.$0.0.1.$2016-09-27T07=200=200=10002016-09-27T08=200=200=1000.6.$type.0.$0"]'),  function (data) {
            return data.textContent;         
            });
        });

It works good but just for one span though.

Why using .map js function cuz phantomjs does not support "complex objects".

Comment: So you just want to get that one value for the given reactid? If you can be a bit more specific I will look into it, I used PhantomJS before. The initial question is answered though, so please accept it as an answer. Post your specifications as comments here and I will post an update to my answer.

Comment: Accepted! As I understand I need adopt your code to this piece of code I already have: Instead return [].map.call and return data.textContent. Basically need to get all spans' values and save them to an array would be the best or json file var content = page.evaluate(function () { return [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-reactid=".0.2.1‌​.$0.0.1.$2016-09-27T‌​07=200=200=10002016-‌​09-27T08=200=200=100‌​0.6.$type.0.$0"]'), function (data) { return data.textContent; }); });

By the way spans do not have children!

Comment: @AlexDnepr added a PhantomJS example. Tried it simpler, but wouldn't run in PhantomJS, though Chrome console was fine with it. Anyway, it grabs the ids and values and writes them to a text file. Regarding `spans don't have children`: but they do have childnodes (there is a difference between child nodes and child elements).

Comment: Ohkay, I am really appreciate your help Frederick! I have tried your example already and it works! Thank you very much for that! As I said I am very new to web development in general so those things cause me a lot of issues especially when JavaScript comes and play.

Comment: That's why I mostly try javascript in the console in chrome, deubgging PhantomJS is not as comfortable (it is still a great tool, much faster than HtmlUnit and with higher success rate to render the content). By the way: no k in my firstname ;-)

Comment: Omg, so sorry! Also, what would you advice for becoming good in JS?

Comment: I like w3cschools (http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) and just trying to solve problems on stackoverflow will broaden your horizon, what I can recommend.

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks a lot! If you need any help you are always welcome!